# Unable to open work file with IIS but work fine when run with VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office

am stuck in very strange issue.
What i am doing is opening a file through Miscrosft Office DLL

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();       
    wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open("C:\\aa.docx");
```

enery thing is working fine till i run my application from visual studio, but when i run it through IIS thne **wordDocument** comming null.

i think it is rights issue but dont know whet to doo. My web site app pool identity is "**LocalSystem**"

Comment: And there are no errors whatsoever?

Comment: Stop. Microsoft have *never* supported automating Word from a service (whether that be a service you write yourself or IIS)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: On that note, perhaps I can throw a little more fuel on the fire: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: no error. i got word object as null

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are two issues:

> 1. You haven't installed Office on the IIS machine
> 2. You have no access to the file specified.

There is another big thing you should consider: Word interop IS NOT RECOMMENDED on an IIS process. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2) Microsoft document.

Comment: I have word 2010 installed on server.

Comment: See the document from Microsoft on how this is not supported. Maybe you can find something similar to epplus (epplus.codeplex.com) which is a wrapper that reads the XLSX files (without Excel).

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, please don't forget to mark your question as answered.