# ASP.NET project opening microsoft word

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my asp.net project i want to make modifications in a word document.
well every thing is working well in local but i want to know if i can make modifications in a word document in the server or i have to install microsoft office with the web site i mean when i make like this

```
aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

will i open word in the server or in the  client computer??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Word Document on Client Side from Asp.net Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335125/opening-word-document-on-client-side-from-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 1):

You [don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188147/unable-to-open-work-file-with-iis-but-work-fine-when-run-with-vs) [to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708653/error-reading-word-doc-using-micorsoft-office-interopobject-library-via-iis-7) [interop in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229932/word-interop-unauthorized-exception-when-run-by-iis). Use a Word library.

But to answer your question, serverside code runs on the server so yes, you'll have to install Office on your web server if you're absolutely sure you want to use interop.

Comment: so what is the best solution to modify a word document with asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

> There would be performance issue if you are trying to open word editor
>   on server or client machine.. If you open a word editor and update the
>   file it means that your are  updating the file so One simple solution
>   is for the user to download the file, edit it and upload it back to
>   you.

Comment: so what is the best solution to modify a word document with asp.net?

Comment: as i suggest just downlaod the file make changes and upload new file there..this will be best approach your server will have less burden of opening of word document.

Comment: how can i make changes in the file without opening microsoft word?

Comment: Client will have to open the any word editing software after downloading the fie from your server then client can make chnages and again upload to server!

Comment: Else you can read your word doc by server side code and display text on the web page then client will be able to edit the text from rich text box and simple save it.In this whole process you will not need any word editor!

Comment: what i want is to edit the word document on the server then download it for the client not the inverse

Answer (score 0):

You've to install Microsoft Office at the server because the Microsoft.Office.Interop uses an actual instance of Word.

Microsoft discourages the use of Word in a server environment as Word is a desktop application. If a dialogue or error occurs while working with the word document there are no way to handle this.

Alternatively, there are several external libraries designed for server use, but I don't know any free ones.

Comment: so what is the best solution to modify a word document with asp.net?